# Can you help me identify the travelers and load

Tags: electrical, wiring

Are the two wires connected to the brass screws travelers ?[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** the 3-way switch is wired correctly, yes the travelers are on the two screws of the same color, while line (at one switch) and load (at the other switch) connect to the one screw of a different color.